# Change the boxplot background based in x-variable (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to change the background of a boxplot based in x-variables. My code is very simple:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
```

So, i have 17 x-variables and i generate 17 boxplots in the same picture. I want to change to grey the background of the boxplots from 1 to 4 and from 11 to 14. I don´t know how can i do that.

Thanks.

Comment: add this to aes: `fill = variable %in% c(1:4, 11:14)` Or whatever names you have for 1:4,11:14 variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create some factor to aid this process. In the example I created a new feature (`tales`) in df.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(variable = rep(base::LETTERS[1:17], 5),
                 value = runif(17*5, 0, 100))
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(tales = rep(c(rep("x", 4), rep("y", 11-4), rep("w", 17-11)), 5))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = tales))
```

[image]